# Definition of locally generated by $\mathscr{S}_1$ as an $\mathscr{O}_X$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry for my bad English.
In Hartshorne's "Alegebaic Geometory" 2.7,p160 (Dagger)

[image]

but, I can't understand mean of "locally generated by $\mathscr{S_1}$"in this case. 
Please tell me exact definition. Thanks.

Comment: You ask about the word "locally" here but it's not in your quoted passage. Can you fix this? Further, questions here are expected to be self-contained - it would improve your question and increase your chances of getting an answer if you could post the full dagger condition here.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I edited  sentence based on your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal for this statement is to globalize the $\operatorname{Proj}$ construction for graded algebras in to a statement for sheaves of graded algebras. The intended definition is that for every open affine subset $U\subset X$, we have that $\mathscr{S}(U)$ is generated by $\mathscr{S}_1(U)$ as a $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-algebra. This is equivalent by the standard manipulations to the statement that there exists a cover of $X$ by open affines $U_i$ so that $\mathscr{S}(U_i)$ is generated by $\mathscr{S}_1(U_i)$ as a $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$-algebra.